# Filtering Data in ASP.NET Web Services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx, production-environment

I've been using this site for quite a while, usually being able to sort out my questions by browsing through the questions and following tags. However, I've recently come across a question that is rather hard to lookup amongst the great number of questions asked - a question I hope some of you might be able to share your opinion on.

As my problem is a bit hard to fit into a single line, going in the title, I'll try to give a bit more details on the problem I've encountered. So, as the title says I need to filter, or limit, some of the response data my standard ASP.NET Soap-based Web service returns on invoking various web methods. The web service is used to return data used by other systems (a data repository more or less), where the client today is able to specify a few parameters on how the data should be filtered and in return a full-set of data back.

Well, easy enough I thought, just put additional filtering options on the existing web methods which needs a bit more filtered applied, make adjustments on the server-side and we are all set to go - well, unfortunately it turned out to be a bit more tricky then this.

The problem I am facing is that I'm working on a web service running in a production environment, which needs to be extended in such that additional filters can be applied to existing web method being invoked w/o affecting the calls already being made by other systems used by the customer using their client stubs. This is where I am a bit troubled, since I can't seem to find a "right solution" on extending the current web service.

Today, the filter is send as a custom data structure which holds information on which data should filtered, but I am not sure if I can simply just add more information to this data structure w/o breaking code at the clients? One of my co-workers suggested that I could implement a solution where I would extend the web.config on the server-side to hold a section with details on which data should be excluded (filtered out), but I don't find this to be a viable solution long-sighted - and I don't trust customers with such an option since this is likely to go wrong at some point. So the solution I am looking for is a way that I can apply a "second filter" to the data I am requesting from the client so instead of getting a full-set of data back it should only give a fraction, it implemented in such that the filter can be easily modified and it must not affect the current client calls.

Any suggestions on how I should approach this problem?

Thanks!
Kind regards,
E.

Comment: is there  reason why you can;t just create a new method for the new customers to use ? The new method would accept additional filter data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty common practice is to create another instance of the application OR use part of the url to signify the version of the endpoint they are connecting to, perhaps the virtual directory is the date. That way old calls will go to the old API and new calls will come in on the new API.

```
http://api.example.com/dostuff
```

vs

```
http://api.example.com/6-7-2011/dostuff
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! After I read your answer, I looked more into web service versioning and it seems like the right choice to go for. So again, thanks for the quick resonse, I'll get cracking on the implementation details.